# MySQL Get rows from position A to position B

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I wanted to know if there was a way to get the rows between two certain positions (aka: within a range). I am using hibernate and I believe it's possible to use .setQuerySize(n) (believe because I am not completely sure) to get a certain block of rows, but I do not know how to make it so that I can get a block from a random position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a provision in MYSQL to use `limit`

Say you want to display the 10 rows, 
append

```
limit 10
```

If you want the first 10 records starting from row 1

append `limit 1,10`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
Select `value` FROM db.table WHERE `value` >= 'A%' AND `value` <= 'B%'
```

Comment: Now I am embarrased that I couldn't think of it as two simple conditions on an id, thanks to you both.